# PHP keep file handle open between pages

Tags: php, file, session, variables

In order to make my PHP app more efficient, I'm trying to keep a file open between pages, saving the file handle to a session variable.  (save to a `$_SESSION['FILEHANDLE']` )

I'm finding that although the  `$_SESSION['FILEHANDLE']` is set between pages, the file handle is NOT saved.  When I print the file handle from the page that opened the file, is shows RESOURCE #5.  When I print the file handle from another page, it shows 0.

Is it possible to keep a file open between pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't save file handling resource in session, nor any resources also that related to file system and connections to other external resources.

Comment: I'm actually opening a unix domain socket (in case that matters) - but I assume the same?  (Can't stay open between pages)?

Comment: No its not, once the php execution finsihed, all opened resources will be closed automatically.